# class.getClassLoader getResourceasStream returns null in jar

Tags: java, maven

I am facing this strange issue while building my project through Maven.

[image]

Here is my code for reading the text file, which I have put under `resources` folder in a Maven project. While Running from IDE everything is fine but once I create a jar and run from command line, it is returning me `null`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    URL jarUrl = FreeCalcTest.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
    System.out.println("JarUrl : "+jarUrl);
    String filePath = "UserDetails\\ReadFile.txt";
    URL url = FreeCalcTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource(filePath);
    System.out.println(url);
    InputStream inputStream = FreeCalcTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath);
    UserDetailReader userDetailReader = new UserDetailReader(inputStream);
    List<UserDetailValueSet> userDetails = userDetailReader.read();
    Set<String> attrList =  UserDetailAttributes.getAttributes();
    Iterator<String> attrItr = attrList.iterator();
    Iterator<UserDetailValueSet> itr = userDetails.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        UserDetailValueSet userDetailValueSet = (UserDetailValueSet) itr.next();
        while (attrItr.hasNext()) {
            String attr = (String) attrItr.next();
            System.out.println(userDetailValueSet.getValueSet().get(attr));
        }

    }
}
```

Exception stacktrace:

```
JarUrl : file:/C:/Users/bnath/Desktop/FreeCalc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Unknown Source) at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sec.io.reader.UserDetailReader.read(UserDetailReader.java:24)
    at com.sec.testFreeCalc.FreeCalcTest.main(FreeCalcTest.java:24)
```

Comment: can you post your stack traces so that we can dig deep into the issue

Comment: How are you building your jar file? Try opening your jar file, e.g. using WinZip. My guess is that `UserDetails\ReadFile.txt` is *not* in there.

Comment: I have checked UserDetails\ReadFile.txt is present in the Jar file. Below is the stack trace                                                        
JarUrl : file:/C:/Users/bnath/Desktop/FreeCalc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.Reader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.sec.io.reader.UserDetailReader.read(UserDetailReader.java:24)
        at com.sec.testFreeCalc.FreeCalcTest.main(FreeCalcTest.java:24)

Comment: @BhupendraNath I've added the stacktrace to the question for you, but please mind that it is normally your job to add additional information to the question. You can do that by clicking the [edit] button under your question.

Comment: Thanks i will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [should use](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) a forward slash as separator for resource paths, therefore try `"UserDetails/ReadFile.txt"`

The classloader is responsible to interpret the path and find the resource. When searching for a resource in the filesystem a path with a backslash seems to work in Windows, probably because it is simple interpreted as relative path.

Such a path does not work when resources inside a JAR file are requested since the format for JAR entries requires the forward slash as separator char.

Comment: Thanks a Lot its working now . When I am giving a backward slash the IDE is converting it into a special character hence in IDE its running fine in Jar its returning null.
With backslash path is coming as 
: file:/D:/workspace/FreeCalc/target/classes/UserDetails%5cReadFile.txt extra %5c is added before the File Name. With Forwards slash its working fine. Can you please tell me why this is happening.

Comment: @BhupendraNath great that it works. For a deeper understanding of the inner workings of classloaders you might want to take a closer look at the standard classloader implementation which is http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/net/URLClassLoader-source.html. And please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted, thanks!